# Run SQL Query From VBA

Tags: sql-server, vba, excel, excel-2013

I am using this syntax to run a SQL Server 2008 stored procedure from Excel 2013.  Everything executes as it should on one PC, but if I attempt to run it on a second PC it errors out with an

> OLEDB Connection error

Shouldn't since I am hardcoding the servername, username, and password the syntax run w/o a hitch on any PC?

```
Function RunSQLServerProc()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Set con = New ADODB.Connection
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=Server;Initial Catalog=Database;User Id=userid;Password=password;Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "TestProc"
Set rs = cmd.Execute(, , adCmdStoredProc)
End Function
```

Comment: This actually executes?  I don't see where you are assigning the connection to the command.  Also, supplying user id and password with `Integrated Security=SSPI` is contradictory.  Surely that is not the entire error message.

Comment: @PaulAbbott - sorry, copy/paste error.  I added in cmd.ActiveConnection = con .... I am only wanting to be able to have any user who opens the workbook be able to execute the connection to SQL Server.  Regardless of the computer it is opened on.

Comment: So are you trying to authenticate with a SQL username and password or the current windows login?

Comment: I want to authenticate with a SQL username and password.

Comment: Then take `Integrated Security=SSPI` out.

Comment: ... and `Trusted_Connection=Yes`... FYI both of those should be for using windows credentials instead of a given username/password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to connect to SQL Server through VBA
1) Integrated Security=SSPI;
2) Provide a valid username & password through the VBA

When you use SSPI, the windows login credentials of the logged in user (i.e. of the Excel workbook) will be used.

Now for you, since you are not wanting to use windows credentials you need to provide a SQL server logon with the User ID and password you specify, and that must also be associated with an account in the database with the privileges that you need.

Answer (score 0):

These two samples work perfectly fine for me.

```
Option Explicit

Sub CallSprocOne()

Dim con As Connection
Dim rst As Recordset
Dim strConn As String

Set con = New Connection
strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;"
strConn = strConn & "Data Source=LAPTOP\SQL_EXPRESS;"
strConn = strConn & "Initial Catalog=Northwind;"
strConn = strConn & "Integrated Security=SSPI;"

con.Open strConn

'Put a country name in Cell E1
Set rst = con.Execute("Exec dbo.TestNewProc '" & ActiveSheet.Range("E1").Text & "'")

'The total count of records is returned to Cell A5
ActiveSheet.Range("A5").CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close
con.Close

End Sub


Sub CallSprocTwo()

Dim con As Connection
Dim rst As Recordset

Set con = New Connection
con.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=LAPTOP\SQL_EXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Set rst = con.Execute("Exec dbo.[Ten Most Expensive Products]")
'Results of SProc are returned to Cell A1
ActiveSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst

rst.Close
con.Close
End Sub
```